# Ros2: OccupancyGrid with RPlidar

Tags: ros2, path, rplidar, planning, occupancygrid

I am looking for places to find information how to create an OccupancyGrid with RPlidar. Everything I find is older or only for ros1.

**I need to create an OccupancyGrid using my RPlidar, the objective is to use the  OccupancyGrid to generate a path planning.**

Answer (score 1):

You're combining two seperate problems here. The first is creating an occupancy grid, the second is getting data from the RPlidar. Remember, one of the main reasons we use ROS is because it allows us to ignore the specific details of our sensors: we don't need to care about how the RPlidar works, we only need to care that it provides laser scan data.

So first, we need to get scan data from the RPlidar. It looks like [there is an official package](https://github.com/Slamtec/sllidar_ros2) to do that. With that package built and sourced, you should be able to `ros2 launch` it. For example, with the RPLidar a1:

```
ros2 launch sllidar_ros2 view_sllidar_a1_launch.py
```

There are other launch files in that repository worth looking at depending on which specific RPLidar device you have.

You should now be producing scan data. You can then make use of the `slam_toolbox` package from either [source](https://github.com/SteveMacenski/slam_toolbox) or via `apt-get install`. You can read more in the [documentation](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_slam.html), but you'll have to launch a mapping node, e.g.,

```
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py
```

Then, you'll need to make sure that the scan being provided to the slam toolbox is on the same topic as being provided by the LIDAR. If it isn't, remap one of the topics so that they're talking to each other, and you should be producing occupancy grids that you can view on the `/map` topic.

I'm assuming here that by 'occupancy grid' you mean 'occupancy grid of the static environment', which would be a map.

Comment: Hi. The environment will have some obstacles but the laser will be in a robot with wheels and the robot will run in a big and open place. The robot creates an occupancy grid and a path planning algorithm like A star or D star creates the path between the obstacles until the goal. My problem is how to populate the occupancy grid.

Comment: Yes, that's the question that I've answered, is there any additional detail you need here?

Comment: I just try to make work now :-) If I found any trouble I back. but big thanks for now!! :-)

Comment: I did everything, now I am stuck in the message - "[slam_toolbox]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'laser' at time 1692328002.091 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'" - What is the error?